# bootstrap class "form-control" don't let use properly label for attribute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In my project i use bootstrap , and here there is a input , and label. they need to be in the same row, but it doesnt work because of using the class form control.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control login-field" id="login-name/>

<label class="glyphicon glyphicon-user login-field-icon" for="login-name"></label>
```

the label goes down because of using the "form-control" class (bootstrap)
and the effect of the for that put the label in the same row, doesnt work anymore.

when i delete the "form-control" class that's work fine, how can i override the limit ?

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) tell you, you have to use `form-inline` class to the form to get elements horizontally aligned.